# Unrecognized token 'title': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I need to sent a request from ajax to java controller.The title field contains some anchor tags.Don't know whether that is creating the issue

My client side ajax request is

```
url="http://localhost:8080/TS/Add"   

var obj = {
            title : title,
            tagnames : categoryIds,
            documentnames : documents,
            linknames : links,
            createdby : userId
    }
    var post = decodeURIComponent($.param(obj))
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : url,
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data : post,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            onComplete();
        }
    });
```

The title field contains

```
title = test <a href="www.google.com" type="0">www.google.com</a>
```

My controller code is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MessageList> addPost(@RequestBody @Valid MessageList messageList, BindingResult bindingResult,
        UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
//Mycode
}
```

Modelclass is

```
public class MessageList extends BaseEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer id;

public float ratenumber;

public int ratecount;

public String title;    
public String tags;
public String documents;
public String links;

@Transient
private ArrayList<String> tagnames;

@Transient
private ArrayList<String> documentnames;

@Transient
private ArrayList<String> linknames;    


//getters and setters
}
```

Error is

```
2017-09-25 09:14:06.518  WARN 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'title': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@370e1ed4; line: 1, column: 10]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'titlenew': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@370e1ed4; line: 1, column: 10]
```

Comment: You can use directly without `decodeURIComponent()` function

Comment: remove `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now I have another issue. Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token for the linknames column